# Affect a json attribute to a variable in angular2

Tags: json, angular

I'm trying to affect the value of a JSON attribute through a variable in Angular 2, I've tried to access it in my app component like this:

```
export class AppComponent{

    count : any;

    constructor(private _getService : GetService) {

        this._getService.getPosts(this.urlG)
            .subscribe(
                result => this.actionsG = result, 
                error=> console.error('Error: ' + error), 
                ()=> console.log('finish! ActionsG')
            ); // getting the JSON FILE

        this.aCount = this.actionsG.actionList[0].count; 

        // that's what i'm trying to do to get the values of count in the json
        // file and stock it into aCount..
    }
}
```

My JSON file :

```
{
    "actionList": {
        "count": 70, //
        "list": [
            {
                "Person": {
                    "name": "David",
                    "age": "30",
                    "id": "D5UG8R",
                   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.aCount = this.actionsG.actionList[0].count;
```

is executed before

```
result => this.actionsG = result
```

Do instead

```
this._getService.getPosts(this.urlG).subscribe(result => {
    this.actionsG = result;
    this.aCount = this.actionsG.actionList[0].count; 
}, error=> console.error('Error: ' + error), ()=> console.log('finish! ActionsG'));
```

Comment: when i've did it and print the value of aCount by : `console.log("acount: " + this.aCount); ` i'm getting the value undefined it mean i can't access the value in the json file by : this.actionsG.actionList[0].count;   when i'm printing it in html i can access it by : {{actionList?.count}} i don't know how to do to get the value on a variable

Comment: You need to do it inside `subscribe(...)` because this code is executed when the response from the server arrives. If you have your code after `subscribe()` it's executed before the response arrives, thus undefined.